# HEIC images in assets produced "CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code "

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, archiving, heic

I am using heic images in image assets to reduce app size, there is no issue while running app on device from Xcode, but it complains "CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code " when i am archiving app for IPA.

I am using Xcode 11.0 and iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem with Xcode 11.4.1.
For me, the solution was renaming .heic images to .png.
It looks like an Apple bug.